# Error in nodes_mis[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions in the mice package using meth="rf"

Tags: r, random-forest, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I am a total novice in R.
I am trying to test the mice package for missing imputation using the random forest method as the imputation algorithm:

```
library(mice)
data <- matrix(c(1.0, 10.5, 1.5, 13.2, 1.8, 8.0, 1.7, 15.0, 23, 40.0, 2.0, 21.0, 3.3, 38.0, 4.5, -2.3, NA, -2.4),nrow=9,ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
impObject <- mice(as.data.frame(data),m=1,meth='rf',printFlag=FALSE)
completedData <- complete(impObject,1)
print(completedData)
```

The code above already gives me the error: `Error in nodes_mis[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions`.

If I use other imputation methods, or if I use slightly modified input data (let's say `data <- matrix(c(1.0, 10.5, 1.5, 13.2, 1.8, 8.0, 1.7, NA, 23, 40.0, 2.0, 21.0, 3.3, 38.0, 4.5, -2.3, NA, -2.4),nrow=9,ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)`) it works.
Is it a bug in the package implementing the rf method for mice (that by the way I can't find its name, it did ask me to install it but I can't retrieve back its name) ?
Eventually, as do you report bugs in R packages ?

Comment: With the example showed, I am not getting any error

Comment: How do I get the installed lib versions in R?

Comment: I used `packageVersion('mice')#
[1] ‘3.13.0’` for testing

Comment: @akrun: I got `> packageVersion('mice') #[1] ‘3.14.0’`. However I believe the problem is in the package implementing rf model for mice, but I can't find its name....

Comment: I ended up filling a bug report in the mice package https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/447#issuecomment-981540056 that is under investigation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has since been solved, which is discussed [here](https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/447#issuecomment-981540056).

In brief, in `mice` version 3.14.0, the default value for the `rfPackage` argument of `mice:::mice.impute.rf` switched from `randomForest` to `ranger` (see [here](https://github.com/amices/mice/pull/431)). When there was only one missing value, something went wrong with subsetting one of the matrices. This has been fixed (see [here](https://github.com/amices/mice/pull/448)) and implement in version 3.14.2.